# Redirecting read requests traffic to AWS Aurora RDS read replica

Tags: spring, hibernate, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

My project is using hibernate. I have created a read replica using the AWS console for Aurora RDS to balance the load. When I make read requests I don't see the requests going to my read replica.

Does Aurora RDS handles the read requests by it's own? or I need to implement this in my application to redirect the read requests traffic to the read replica.

I checked multiple articles and I didn't find any information on built in functionality to redirect read requests.

[Article 1](https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2022/04/24/Spring-Boot-AWS-RDS-Read-Replica-Part-2/): This article suggests to use Spring cloud dependency and annotate the transactions with readOnly=true

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

[Article 2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/requests-rds-read-replicas/): This article suggests to use the Route 53 and use the weighted class

I will have only one writer instance and one read replica. Need some help on choosing which method is a better option.

If there is a built in functionality in Aurora RDS how do I use.

Is there any other alternative apart from the above two?

Comment: No it doesn't. You need to direct read only requests to the [reader endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html#Aurora.Endpoints.Reader). You could do this via custom read only repositories that connect to the reader endpoint instead of the cluster endpoint, or perhaps 2 different data sources within Java.

Comment: Article 1 is for RDS read replicas and it seems that `spring-cloud-aws-jdbc` still does not have support for Aurora, from a quick glance at the Github repository. Article 2 is also for RDS read replicas and not for Aurora - please ignore it. The reader endpoint load-balances connections to available Aurora Replicas in an Aurora DB cluster automatically; you do not need weighted Route 53 records.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary do we need to direct read only requests to reader endpoint even if we use Aurora serverless V2 DB instance?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary can we provide two JDBC urls in hibernate one for write requests and another for read requests?